# What is happening when the uploaded PDF is under "converting", and why PDF converting is necessary?

Tags: html, pdf

For many website that allow users to upload PDF files, for example, hiring website that allow users to upload their CV in PDF format, and many academic conference website that allow users to submit papers in PDF format, once the upload button is clicked, it is very common to see something like "the PDF file is being converted...". And after a while, the uploaded PDF is ready for preview through a link. And when such link is clicked, it will usually open a new webpage and display the PDF in formats such as HTML.

I am curious of the following:

1. Why PDF needs to be "converted", why can't the website just accept the PDF and then store it for preview, just like regular FTP server?
2. What is really happening when an PDF is being converted? Will any information be lost?

Thank you!

Comment: "It depends" - you need to list some specific site.  Also, browsers don't display PDFs themselves using their normal HTML engine, they rely on a separate "plugin."  That means the behavior will be different, things like dark mode, history, links won't work the same for a PDF.  Some sites might do the conversion for the better experience, some might do it for security, or to convert to searchable / indexable text, to store information in a database ... "it depends".

Comment: Also, please read [tour] and [ask].  As it is written now this will probably be closed as "too broad" since it isn't really a specific programming question.

Comment: Thank you for your comment and suggestion, I found it better fits Stack Exchange and will definitely post such questions there next time!